# Predicate Logic - translation

Tags: logic

How can I translate the following sentence into Predicate Logic: "I hate flies" (F – [1] are flies, G – [1] hate [2], а – I). I was thinking of ∃a(Fx∧Gx), is the sentence correct?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is an analogue of "I" in predicate logic (at least, as far as mathematics is concerned). By this I mean that you should not be able to devise a string which, interpreted as of content, means "Everyone who is User14414 satisfies the property P" if you write it and which means "Everyone who is Gae S. satisfies the property P" if I write it.

Comment: Do you hate all flies, or just some flies?

Comment: $\forall x(Fx\supset Hx)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your translation would apply if there exists least one fly that you hate. Saying "I hate flies" suggests that you hate ALL flies.

Instead, how about:

$\forall x: [Fly(x) \implies IHate(x)]$

where $Fly$ and $IHate$ are unary predicates.

Answer (score 0):

No. $G$ needs two argument: the hater and the hated.  The hater is 'I', i.e. $a$, and the hated is flies .... and presumably *all* flies!

So, you need a universal statement, and you'll need $Gax$ in there.

Try again.

Answer (score 0):

$aGF$, or $G(a,F)$, or $GaF$, depend on the notation you choose to use.

Perhabs this helps : $a$ and $F$ are constants whereas $G$ is binary relation.